# Unreadable string matches a regex consisting of readable characters only

Tags: bash, regular-expression

Consider the commands below:

```
STR="Êîðîëü è Øóò"; # Invalid (Russian in unrecognized encoding)
#STR="а б в г д"; # Valid (Russian)
#STR="a b c d e"; # Valid (English)
#STR="a b c d e а б в г д"; # Valid (English and Russian)



# The regex consists of latin and Russian characters
REGEX="^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я ]+$"

if ! [[ "$STR" =~ $REGEX ]] ; then
  echo "Unreadable string: ""$STR";
fi


$ echo $LC_ALL
ru_RU.UTF-8
```

I expected `"Unreadable string: Êîðîëü è Øóò"` as output but there wasn't anything.

Comment: Try to set `LC_ALL=C`. Btw, I don't consider these chars to be unreadable. Call it "non-ANSI" or something.

Comment: In the C locale, I get the "Unreadable string" output. What locale are you using?

Comment: @Kusalananda Has locale anything to do with this?. I just want to detect a string which doesn't contain latin and/or Russian characters. STR is one of such strings. It contains trash (Russian characters in wrong encoding, say unreadable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What ranges like `A-Z` or `а-я` match is unspecified by POSIX other than in the POSIX locale (for `A-Z`, not `а-я` obviously).

Only in the POSIX locale can you get the guarantee that `[A-Z]` matches on the `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` characters only.

In other locales, the behaviour varies between implementations. Some may match on any collating element (can be characters or sequences of characters) that sorts after `A` and before `Z` (may include `ch`, `x` or `Á`, but not `Ź` for instance), or they could match on characters whose code point is greater than that of `A` and less than that of `Z` in the locale's charset, or they could use the locale's collation data in yet a different way... Also note that not everybody agrees on the order of letters for any given script (like Latin or Cyrillic in that case), so you'll get different behaviours for different locales that include those scripts in their character set (even if it's the same character set)).

If you want to match any alphabetic character in any script, use `[[:alpha:]]`, if you want to match character ranges based on code point in UTF-8, you could try using the `C.UTF-8` locale available on many systems.

If you want to match on any letter in the Latin script, you could use `perl` or `pcre`'s `\p{Latin}` (includes `é`, `Ê`...). In `zsh`:

```
set -o rematchpcre
[[ $x =~ '^(\p{Latin}|\p{Cyrillic})$' ]]
```

You could restrict the Latin letter to those only found in ASCII with (still with `zsh` and still with `rematchpcre`):

```
[[ $x =~ '^((?=[[:ascii:]])\p{Latin}|\p{Cyrillic})$' ]]
```

though in effect with `rematchpcre`, `^([a-zA-Z]|\p{Cyrillic})$` would have the same effect, as ranges in PCRE and in `zsh` are based on codepoint value and those letters are guaranteed to have the same codepoints and be in that English-alphabet sequence  with all locales on ASCII based and EBCDIC based POSIX systems at least.

Or you can list the characters explicitly if you only want a subset, to avoid all ambiguity:

```
[[ $x =~ ^[ABC...XYZabc...xyzабв...эюя]$ ]]
```

You can always store them in variables like:

```
ascii_upper=ABC...XYZ
ascii_lower=abc...xzy
cyr_upper=...
[[ $x =~ ^[$ascii_upper$ascii_lower$cyr_upper...]$ ]]
```

Comment: Thank you. I've decided to list all the acceptable characters. The regex became longer but this approach is clearer to me and it works.